# Arrow disappearing

Tags: arrows, tikz-qtree

For some reason the arrow between S/V/NP and V'V is not drawn. I have no idea why ...

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every roof node/.append style={inner sep=0.1pt,text height=2ex,text depth=0.3ex}}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\sliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$\left\langle\mbox{\scshape #1}\right\rangle$}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1+/.style={level distance=3\baselineskip},
frontier/.style={distance from root=15\baselineskip},
connect/.style={semithick,<->,color=green}]
\Tree[.S
        [.\node (NP) {NP}; bogen ]
        [.\node (S/NP) {S/NP};
          [.{V \sliste{ S//V }} 
            [.V læser$_k$ ] ]
           [.\node (S//V/NP) {S/V/NP};
             [.NP Jens ]
             [.\node (V/V) {V$'$V};
               [.{V//V}  trace ]
               [.\node (NP/NP) {NP/NP}; trace ] ] ] ] ] ]
\draw[connect] (NP/NP.north east) [bend right] to (V/V.south east);
\draw[connect] (V/V.north east) [bend right] (S//V/NP.south east);
\draw[connect] (S//V/NP.north east) [bend right] to (S/NP.east);
\draw[connect] (S/NP.north east) [bend right] to (NP);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a curious question: why are you naming the node by `(S//V/NP)` with double slash if its contents is `{S/V/NP}` with single slash (between `S` and `V`)?

Comment: This is what the node was in the original example, I simplified the stuff in the tree but left it in the node labels. Linguistically this tree does not make sense ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is missing `to` between the nodes `(V/V.north east)` and `(S//V/NP.south east)`

```
\draw[connect] (V/V.north east) [bend right] to (S//V/NP.south east);
```

[image]

### Sugestion

What do you think to change some anchors to obtain new arrows, as below?

[image]

```
\draw[connect] (NP/NP.north east)   [bend right] to (V/V.east);
\draw[connect] (V/V.north east)     [bend right]    (S//V/NP.east);
\draw[connect] (S//V/NP.north east) [bend right] to (S/NP.east);
\draw[connect] (S/NP.north west)    [bend right] to (NP);
```

Comment: Well, yes in principle your suggestion looks better, but the idea is to connect the NPs. I asked in another question about a way to do this, but this seems to be impossible with `tikz-qtree`.